# css table tr:hover - выключить для определенных строк

Tags: css, hover

Есть таблица на стилях, в стиле по умолчанию прописана подсветка строк `tr:hover`, все круто — удобно и работает, НО есть моменты, когда подсветка не нужна, что нужно прописать, чтобы отключить подсветку для определенных строк?

Comment: Наверно методом ТЕЛЕПАТИИ мы должны догадаться при каких моментах подсветка не должа работать? )) можете хоть написать при каких действий недолжно быть подсветки.... ))

Comment: Эмм... Где прописать? В каких ситуациях? Почему вы не можете importent добавить?

Comment: видимо должно быть только `tr:hover:nth-child(ТУТ_УСЛОВИЕ)`

Answer (score 4):

Вы не дали достаточно исходных данных, поэтому мой ответ очень общий:

Самый простой способ — пометить классом нужную строку. Допустим, мы назовем его `nohover`. Тогда нам нужно сделать селектор отменяющий действие `tr:hover`. Если, например, у подсветка прописана так:

```
.hovertable tr:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

То нужно добавить класс `.nohover`:

```
.hovertable tr.nohover:hover {
```

а `background` выключить:

```
background: none;
```

Рабочий пример:

```css
.hovertable tr:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}
.hovertable tr.nohover:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="hovertable" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>Обычная строка</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="nohover">
    <td>Строка у которой убрана подсветка</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Обычная строка</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте селектор nth-of-type (условие)

Comment: Рекомендую на будущее писать более развёрнутые ответы. Да вот соседний от Crantisz ответ хотя бы посмотрите в качестве образца. А такие короткие как у вас обычно и не плюсуют. Как минимум. А иногда и минус могут поставить.